# Retrieve the drop-down values from database and show the retrieved value as selected one with other drop down list items

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am new in asp.net so may be this is the foolish question I am going to ask but I am suffering from it. I am making a application in which firstly user fill all the details such as country state and city when submit the application it shows preview. The problem comes when in Edit operation all other data is retrieved along with all elements drop down list shows only the retrieved value ...I want to show the retrieved value as selected with the others value as well in the list... because if user wants to change his/her selected value then how will he/ she change the value...

I am using drop-down list.items.add to show the retrieved value from the database ...

Comment: Are you using web forms or MVC? 
Could you show a code example?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to write some code and if you get stuck, post the code and explain where you got stuck. 
Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Any efforts "You" have made for the assignment?